# How to check if a folder is empty or not and use its content in an if-then-else-statement?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I need to check if a folder is empty or not and according to the output I need to run some other commands. I'm working on Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS.

My bash script:

```
if [ "$(ls -A /mnt/mamdrive/"As Metadata"/)" ] || ["$(ls -A /mnt/mamdrive/"As Video"/)"  ]; then
    echo "copy file"
else
    echo "dont copy"
fi
```

The condition works sometimes, but sometimes it doesn't and it's hard to reproduce it. Is there any other way to check if the directory is empty and do some action accordingly?

Comment: Are the spaces in the second statement a typo?

Comment: This got asked over at UNIX&Linux (it's not really Ubuntu specific): https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/204572/100496

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'd suggest something that doesn't rely on the string output of `ls` - for example, testing if there are any results of a glob expansion:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob       # don't return literal glob if matching fails
shopt -s dotglob        # make * match "almost all" like ls -A

set -- /mnt/mamdrive/"As Metadata"/*

if (( $# > 0 )); then
  echo "not empty"
else
  echo "empty"
fi
```

If you want to test whether two directories are both empty, you can simply glob both of them:

```
set -- /mnt/mamdrive/"As Metadata"/* /mnt/mamdrive/"As Video"/*
```

Comment: Is there a straightforward way to do this without clobbering the args provided to the script?

Comment: @JakeRobb since bash supports arrays in general (not only `$@`) you can do something like `files=( /mnt/mamdrive/"As Metadata"/* )` and then `(( ${#files[@]} > 0 ))`

Comment: Perfect, thank you.

Comment: shopt is not defined in POSIX sh.

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way is to use `ls -A` in an `if` statement like this:

```
path=$(ls -A '/whatever/sub directory/more spaces')
if [[ ! -z "$path" ]]; then
    echo "Directory is NOT empty!"
else
    echo "Directory is empty!"
fi
```

Comment: Parsing `ls(1)` is tricky. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/204572/100496 for a discussion on that.

Comment: @ljrk This answer is totally sound. Although it parses `ls`, it only checks if the output is empty or not. If OP wants to do something more with the output, that would be discouraged, but it is not clear in the question what actions he wants to perform. That's a problem with the question, not the answer. Also, the two first lines can be collapsed into `if [ -n "$(ls -A '/whatever/sub directory/more spaces')" ]; then`

Comment: @Quasímodo I'm pretty sure `ls -A` is allowed to output even a line if the directory is empty, if not e.g. `-l` is given. Cf. https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ls.html

Comment: the solution will not scale well on large directories.

Answer (score 1):

`find` in conjunction with `ifne` can work as a copy-on-empty:

```
$ find test/ -maxdepth 0 -empty | ifne cp -t test/ a
```

Using it in an if statement can look something like this:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

if find test/ -maxdepth 0 ! -empty | ifne false; then
   echo Directory is empty
else
   echo Directory is not empty
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

I have been using the following to check if folder is empty or not and so far it has always worked

```
if [ $(ls -al folder_name | wc -l) -gt 3 ];then echo "not empty";else echo "empty";fi
```

Answer (score 0):

As `ls` parsing is very well known to be error-prone because it was not intended to be parsable to begin with, other solutions should be preferred. In addition to @steeldriver's answer, this could also be done using `find`:

```bsh
if [[ "$(find '/mnt/mamdrive/As Metadata' '/mnt/mamdrive/As Video' -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 2>/dev/null)" ]]
then
    echo “copy file”
else
    echo "don't copy"
fi
```

`maxdepth` and `mindepth` options are used here to only print and scan direct children of specified directories. Redirect ensures that error messages will not be printed if some arguments do not exist.

Adding multiple dirs will work as OR, so "copy file" will be printed if at least one of tested dirs is non-empty. Using `find` also allows for finer tuning using its arguments, like file names, file types and so much more.